# Optional parameter x times

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm stucked on something that may seem easy for many here.
I'm looking for a way to filter query results with optional parameters for the same field.

Let's I have a table with COUNTRY (USA, UK) and TOWN (NY,DALLAS,LONDON,LIVERPOOL,MANCHESTER).

```
select COUNTRY, TOWN from MyTable where COUNTRY = :1 AND (TOWN = :2 OR TOWN = :3)
```

The first parameter is compulsory. The two others are optional.

```
select COUNTRY, TOWN from MyTable where COUNTRY = :1 
and (
    TOWN = case when :2 is null then TOWN end 
    OR TOWN = case when :3 is null then TOWN end
)
```

doesn't work.

How can I do with these optional parameters ?

Thx a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like following:

```
select COUNTRY, TOWN 
  from MyTable 
 where COUNTRY = :1 
   AND ((TOWN = :2 OR :2 is null)
         OR (TOWN = :3 OR :3 is null))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
where COUNTRY = :1 and
      ( (:2 is null and :3 is null) or TOWN in (:2, :3))
```

Typically you want to avoid `case` expressions in the `where` clause.  And often the regular boolean expression is simpler.

Comment: This is better than my solution. But what if either 2 or 3 can be Null ?

Comment: @KMarron . . . If one is `NULL` it doesn't matter.  The `in` will still match the other.